# How to Stop TableView from Dequeuing When Page is Refreshed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a Weather Application project and my TableView keeps dequeuing whenever I am going to my settings page and returning. So for example, the TableView has a list of days from Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed, etc, whenever I leave the page to go into the Apps settings and return, the TableView has one less day on top. So it goes from Sun, Mon, Tues, Wed, to Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs.

Where can I change the code to make it continue it TableView functionality without dequeuing whenever the page is refreshed?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "weatherCell", for: indexPath) as? WeatherCell {
    let forecast = forecasts[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(forecast: forecast)
    return cell
} else {
    return WeatherCell()
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the dequeueing. Sounds like your table view is reloading and your data model has one less row in it. Or is the table view just scrolling?

Comment: Probably not related, but that dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) function always returns a cell, so you don't need the if let else statement. If there isn't a cell available then the cell will be created for you.

Comment: The tableView is performing as it should. When you display your settings page, the cells are no longer required, so they get destroyed. When you redisplay the tableView it recreates the visible cells. It sounds like you have a logic error in the construction of `forecasts` or in the `numberOfRowsInSection` function.

Comment: Michael and all, you are absolutely correct! Thank you.